# Another InstantiationException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I'm having a InstantiationException, I have searched the other answers and questions on here but can't find anything related to my problem.
The app crashes on the MainActivity looking at the logcat it gives an error with this

```
mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
```

I have declared it with

```
private String[] mTitles;
```

It is taken from the "Navigation Drawer" example provided by google, I'm just playing and modifying it (learning) but this problem has become a real pain.

Heres the log

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.prowapps.seaport/com.prowapps.seaport.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.prowapps.seaport.MainActivity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.prowapps.seaport.MainActivity
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object   reference
           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:94)
           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
           at com.prowapps.seaport.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:695)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
```

If anyone can shed any light on this it would be really helpful, Thanks

EDIT

/*******************Navigation Drawer************************/

```
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // Set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Comment: Where in your activity is mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);  being called?

Comment: Can you post the code near line 695 in `MainActivity`? I'm looking at this the line from the stack trace: `com.prowapps.seaport.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:695)`

Comment: It is after On create. line 695 is mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);

Comment: are you sure onCreate() is called before?
sry my last comment was wrong thread :D

Comment: Oh no..... @ZerO you're right..argh! this has been troubling me all day all because of a random " { " that found its way in to the code. Thanks for the help. Not sure why it didnt warn me though?

Comment: @ZerO if you want to add it as an answer i will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized your variable `mTitles;` before calling onCreate() function ;)